# Sorting an Array by key, numerically

Tags: php, arrays, array-key, ksort

I want to sort the arrays numerically, i.e. 188, 188-1, 188-2, 222, 222-1, 222,-2 etc. This is how the array currently looks:

```
[188-1] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1
    )

[188-2] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2
    )

[188-3] => Array
    (
        [time] => 3
    )

[188] => Array
    (
        [notes] => frog stand notes
    )

[489] => Array
    (
        [notes] => notes
    )

[489-1] => Array
    (
        [weight] => 10
        [reps] => 30
    )

[489-2] => Array
    (
        [weight] => 20
        [reps] => 30
    )

[489-3] => Array
    (
        [weight] => 30
        [reps] => 30
    )

[492-1] => Array
    (
        [weight] => 500
        [distance] => 100000
    )

[492] => Array
    (
        [notes] => more notes
    )
```

I've tried a ksort, `ksort($sorted, SORT_DESC);` but it doesn't work too well with hyphenated keys, unless I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You might check out: http://sourcefrog.net/projects/natsort/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`uksort()`](http://php.net/uksort) with [`strnatcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) as comparison function:

```
uksort($array, 'strnatcmp');
```